# How to import opencv in python?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, image-processing

It is opencv 3.4.1 *86. i've placed it showing tutorial step by step but it doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/):

> Q: Import fails on Windows: ImportError: DLL load failed: The
>   specified module could not be found.?
>
> A: If the import fails on Windows, make sure you have Visual C++
>   redistributable 2015 installed. If you are using older Windows version
>   than Windows 10 and latest system updates are not installed, Universal
>   C Runtime might be also required.
>
> If the above does not help, check if you are using Anaconda. Old
>   Anaconda versions have a bug which causes the error, see this issue
>   for a manual fix.

[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)